# Are the derivatives of the Busy Beaver function positive?

Tags: sequences-and-series, turing-machines

Let $BB:\mathbb Z_{\ge1}\to\mathbb Z$ be the Busy Beaver sequence, usually called the Busy Beaver *function*, as defined in terms of Turing machines in Section 1.3 of [this text](http://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf) of Aaronson and Yedidia. We have in particular $BB(1)=1$, $BB(2)=6$, $BB(3)=21$, $BB(4)=107$.

The *derivative* of a function $f:\mathbb Z_{\ge1}\to\mathbb Z$ is the function $f':\mathbb Z_{\ge1}\to\mathbb Z$ defined by 
$$
f'(n):=f(n+1)-f(n),
$$ 
and, for $k\in\mathbb N$, the function $f^{(k)}:\mathbb Z_{\ge1}\to\mathbb Z$ is defined by $f^{(k)}:=f$ if $k=0$ and $f^{(k)}:=(f^{(k-1)})'$ if $k\ge1$. (Here $\mathbb Z_{\ge1}$ is the set of positive integers.)

Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers. Is the integer $BB^{(k)}(n)$ positive?

Comment: $BB(n+1)$ eventually grows faster than any computable function of $BB(n)$, so eventually, yes. Incidentally, I think "finite difference" is more standard here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Thank you very much for your comment! I agree that "finite difference" is more standard, but I have a slight preference for sticking to this nonstandard terminology. Do you mean that, for each $k$, there is an $n_k$ such that $BB^{(k)}(n)$ is positive for $n\ge n_k$? (Feel free to upgrade your comment to an answer.)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not known whether $BB^(2)$ is always positive, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Related: (1) [Does the kth forward difference of Radó's Σ eventually dominate every computable function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/does-the-kth-forward-difference-of-rad%C3%B3s-sigma-eventually-dominate-every-c), and (2) [Does Σ(n+1)−Σ(n) eventually dominate every computable function?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9157/does-sigman1-sigman-eventually-dominate-every-computable-function).